# Scripting issue in Silk performer

Tags: silk-performer

While replaying the script in silk performer tool I get the following error:

> WebFormPostBin(HTTP: 1014 - WWW-Authenticate header is missing but status code was 401., RespHdrGetHdr)

please let me know how to resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it's not a problem on your script or recording, but a missing header on the server side.

Silk Performer recommends to consult the system administrator in order to ensure the server is configured to send this header: https://community.microfocus.com/t5/Silk-Performer-Knowledge-Base/On-replay-why-am-I-getting-an-error-quot-HTTP-1014-WWW/ta-p/1756195